# ADB Backup - location of the resulting file?

Tags: android, adb

I used an adb command to backup a file in data/data of an Android phone. After the command ran, my phone said it was successfully backed up, but where is the backup file?

Comment: What command did you use to back up your phone's data?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I used adb backup -noapk com.masimo.merlin.consumer. I only backed up a file in data/data.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `adb backup -all` command then it will create `backup.ab` file in the current working directory.

If you want to specify path use -f like below

```
adb backup -f <path_to_backup_file> -all
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you run

```
 adb backup -noapk com.masimo.merlin.consumer
```

then backup.ab gets stored in the present working directory by default.
In unix/linux, you can know your present working directory by typing **pwd** and in windows you can know it by typing **cd**

[More Info](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351) about backup